# Membership.GetUser() advisable to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I need GUID (UserId) at many places in my application. Currently I am making calls to `Membership.GetUser()` to get the UserId. Does this method make a database call or it caches the details?

If it makes a database call then it is better to store in Session. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Membership.GetUser()` method gets the information from the data source and updates the last-activity date/time stamp for the current logged-on membership user.

You might want to implement `IIdentity` with a UserId property so it will be part of the authentication ticket..

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does make a call to the database, best thing to do as soon as you authenticate your user you can then use session to stored userid.